# Working with Json Data and pouchdb

Tags: json, pouchdb

I've just been introduced to pouchdb and as a side project, I want to create a bible app. The bible content is stored in a json file (js/bible.json). As users read the bible they can favorite different verse and add notes which would be saved with pouchdb. All of these works fine. The problem is, I'd like to display an icon for favorite verses which has been stored with pouchdb.

How do I query pouchdb data base to check if a verse has been "favorited" and display an icon?

I've explored so many options and it's not working. Any help?

Comment: so your problem is that you cannot get an image file from db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pouchdb-find` for this: http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/

Notice how the demo allows you to look up Nintendo characters by various criteria (year of debut, rank, etc.). Similarly, you can search your bible entries by `doc.isFavorited`.

Comment: Bible content is stored in bible.json file. When you favorite a verse, verse.id is saved in pouchdb. As I loop through the verses of a chapter on data gotten from bible.json, how can I check pouchdb for verse.id to determine if a verse has been favorited? OR is there a way to pre-populate pouchdb?

Comment: You can lookup any document by `_id` using `get()`. Or you can lookup multiple documents by id by using `allDocs()` with the `keys` option. For anything that's not `_id`, I recommend `pouchdb-find`.